# Script for calling the action not working when I use datepicker jQuery script in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

Script for calling the action is not working when I use datepicker jQuery script in mvc4

Without using datepicker it works just fine, and the action is called.

My index page

```
@{

Layout = null;

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Company Registration</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputfocus-0.9.min.js"></script>

  //script for calling the action method
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.main.js"></script>
//datepicker jquery
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/CompanyRegister.css" />

    <script>    
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('"#startdttxt"').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
</script>

}
```

I don't know where I'm wrong can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you are loading multiple versions of jQuery? You need to change the sequence of library reference.

Comment: then what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these files and in the following sequence.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputfocus-0.9.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.main.js"></script>
```